# remove the value if i change to no using jquery select dropdown

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

Hi i have this select dropdown list which has the yes and no only. when i select yes the other dropdown select will appear then when i select no the dropdown will disappear. Im using this as jquery hide. I want that when i select yes the other dropdown will appear and when i select no the other dropdown will hide but when i click to yes, i want that , that the value in the selected will be reset. Heres my code below

```
<div class="form-group" style="float:left;">
    <label for="Inputhavepets">Have pets<sup>*</sup></label>
    <select name="have_pets" id="have_pets" class="form-control" >
      <option value="0">-----SELECT ONE-----</option>
      <option value="1">Yes</option>
      <option value="2">No</option>

    </select>      
</div>
<div id="pet_hide" class="form-group" style="float:left;" >
    <label for="Inputhavepetsdog">&nbsp;</label>
    <select name="pets_hide" class="form-control" >
      <option value="0">-----SELECT PET-----</option>
      <option value="1">Dog</option>
      <option value="2">Cat</option>

    </select>      
</div>
```

heres my jquery code below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#pet_hide").hide();
     $('#have_pets').on('change', function() {
          //alert( this.value ); // or $(this).val()
          var pet = $('#have_pets').val();
          if(pet == 1){
            $("#pet_hide").show();
          }else{
            $("#pet_hide").hide();


          }
     });
  });
</script>
```

Can someone help me figured this out? Any help is muchly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try out `$("#pet_hide option:eq(0)").attr("selected","selected");` to select the first value i.e. to reset the selection

Comment: with your code? ok ill try your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#pet_hide").hide();
     $('#have_pets').on('change', function() {
          //alert( this.value ); // or $(this).val()
          var pet = $('#have_pets').val();
          if(pet == 1){
            $("#pet_hide option:first").prop('selected',true); // <--------value '0' will be selected
            $("#pet_hide").show();
          }else{
            $("#pet_hide").hide();
          }
     });
  });
</script>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tp8erar9/1/)

Comment: @hello...strange it will work see carefully there must be problem somewhere else...

Comment: heres my select name code
<select name="pets_hide" class="form-control" >
      <option value="0">-----SELECT PET-----</option>
      <option value="1">Dog</option>
      <option value="2">Cat</option>

    </select>

Comment: i want that when i select no then select to yes the other dropdown select will be reset to 0

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#pet_hide").hide();
     $('#have_pets').on('change', function() {
          var pet = $('#have_pets').val();
          if(pet == 1){
            $('select[name="pets_hide"] option:first').prop('selected', true);
            $("#pet_hide").show();

          }else{

            $("#pet_hide").hide();

          }
     });
  });
```